# Installing Windows 7 after Ubuntu on MacbookPro 8,2

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, system-installation, macbook-pro

I have an extremely long troubleshooting narrative, but here are what I believe to be the most crucial features. I own a MacbookPro 8,2. Currently running Ubuntu exclusively.

1. I attempted to re-partition my hard drive so that I could use Mac OSX as little as possible and get introduced to Linux OS's via Ubuntu. I downloaded and installed rEFIt, burned an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS image to a dvd, and installed Ubuntu on the partition that I installed. However, I think I messed up the boot records or something, because it did not boot into rEFIt, and I could not get the Ubuntu grubs to give me the option to boot to Mac OSX. Therefore I just said screw it and re-partitioned my hard drive to it's current state, which i will show below:

| BIOS 1MB | Ext 4 (Ubuntu Partition), 455 GB | Swap, 5 MB | NTFS, 295 GB |
| /dev/sda1|       /dev/sda2                  | /dev/sda3  |  /dev/sda4   |

I really want to install Windows to /dev/sda4, the NTFS formatted partition. I torrented a .iso for Windows 7, but no matter what I cannot get my computer to boot to the dvd that I burned of this image. I have tried mashing c, F2, F1, esc, and F12 while booting the machine. When I manage to get to any type of boot options screen, it's the ubuntu GRUBS where it does not give me the option to boot to the disk.

A few questions:

1. What pieces of information do I need to supply myself and the viewers of this page with such that I might correct the problem?
2. Do I need to convert the Windows 7 .iso to a .img (or .dmg) before I can boot to it in the macbook DVD drive? I didn't need to for the Ubuntu install.
3. Would it be possible to re-install Mac OS X Mavericks and try from the beginning again? I have a LaCie hard drive that I had synced with Time Machine. Is there anyway I can use this to simply revert back to how my hard drive was before I messed with anything? (Yes, I know I should have backed up all of my information more properly before re-partitioning or messing around with a new OS.....)

Thanks, and let me know if I can do anything to make the solution more apparent.
-t

Comment: I recommend you boot to Linux (use an emergency disc, if necessary) and run the [Boot Info Script.](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bootinfoscript/) This will create a file called `RESULTS.txt`. Post it to [a pastebin site](http://paste.ubuntu.com/) and post the URL to your document here. This will give us detailed information about your current setup, without which almost any answer will be based on guesswork. (The main exception would be instructions on blowing away the hard disk and starting from scratch.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the BIOS properly yet?  It loads before GRUB, and has its own set of settings - normally you can get it by mashing F12 *instantly* after hitting the power button.  GRUB will only boot from your HDD, and if the BIOS is not configured so that it will check the DVD drive first, you will only ever see GRUB.  Still, the BIOS settings won't let you directly boot from the DVD, it'll set it so it'll check the DVD drive for a bootable image before it checks the HDD and goes to GRUB.

After everything works, you boot from disk, install Windows, and you're done, Windows will kindly overwrite the master boot record so that it only points to itself, making it impossible to boot to Ubuntu.  Typically you should always install Windows first, because it's greedy, but eh, it's still fixable.

Burn [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/) to an .iso and load and run it *after* Windows is installed.  It'll restore the boot log and you'll see GRUB again and everything should be happy.

Comment: lane0335 has a Mac, which doesn't have a PC-style BIOS screen accessed by hitting a function key. (Even on PCs, it's often Delete or a function key other than F12 that enters the firmware setup utility.) The Master Boot Record (MBR) is also unimportant on Macs and other EFI-based computers, except to the extent that a dual-booting Mac uses the MBR to boot Windows in BIOS emulation mode.

Comment: Damn, my non-mac-user is showing.  I really ought to delete this answer, no?

Comment: thanks for answering, but I ended up just re-installing everything. I appreciate the help, though.